# Get list of all currently visible ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that implements a slide out navigation drawer. When I am on a certain view controllers and choose to go somewhere else in the app, I want to pop a modal from the view controller I'm leaving to confirm that the user wants to leave that page.

The problem is, I need a reference to that view controller to call a delegate method I already have established for this, which does all the checks it needs to. How can I get a reference to ALL currently visible view controllers on screen?

I've tried getting the root view controller and then accessing its child view controllers, I've tried getting the navigation controller and then accessing its view controllers, but none of these have worked.

Basically, I just need a way to get a reference to everything view controller that is on screen, if there is a way to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need a reference to all visible view controllers? Why not just maintain a reference to only the one you want to pop?

Comment: Or use unwind segue.

Comment: I'm not sure why "none of these have worked".  I'm pretty sure the last VC on the nav controller's stack should be the top-level VC, right?